# is it necessary to use db:migrate for working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-connection

Is it necessary to use db:migrate?

I have existing database, i want to write ROR classes for this and synchronize with DB.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not. Your class name just has to match the table name. However, I would warn you that working with Active Record (the rails orm by default) against an existing db that doesn't have the ar conventions is going to be a huge pain. I would recommend checking out datamapper, and using rails 3 (since alternative orms in rails 3 is way easier)

Comment: One bandaid (that postpones the pain for a short while) is to create views that conform to the Rails convention. Not recommended for anything other than fooling around, though (i.e., if you let this 'solution' creep into production, you're in for a world of hurt).